# Get Accordian Selected Index in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

Im working on an ASP.Net app with c#. I am stuck on a problem with an accoridian.

My accordian correctly displays data from a datasource which in this case in some text and then a list of images. On each accordians content there are the images to be displayed and then a button to add another image.

This button links to another page that contains the add form. From here I am able to add an image and it forwards me back to the page displaying the accoridan with one new image in the correct section.

**Now The problem is that I want to re-open the section that was previously open.**

I have tried a couple different ways but all of them have not worked. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are redirecting to another page, you are going to have to pass the currently opened section to it via a querystring and then when the new page sends you back, it'll send you back the same value so you know which one to open.

Another quick way would be to pop it into a session and then read from that session. But I would recommend the query string route, it has less overhead.